# Button slide after fill all required inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom-events

I have a form with classic text boxes And textarea. All inputs are required. 
I want to show submit button only when this fields are filled. Submit button must be animated (slide from right).

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help when you get stuck in your code and not supply code or outside resources. If you have started coding please edit your question and add in your code and someone can help.

Comment: Can you show us what your code looks like so far and pin-point your most troubling issue so we can help that first?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. Hope it will help you.

```js
var text = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var btn = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

function btnShow () {
  if (text.value != "" && textarea.value != "") {
    btn.style.left = 0;
  } else {
    btn.style.left = "-40%";
  }
}

text.addEventListener('keyup', btnShow);
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', btnShow);
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -9.5%;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required> <br><br>
<textarea required></textarea> <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let formObj = document.querySelector('#my-form');
let emailObj = document.querySelector('#email');
let passObj = document.querySelector('#password');
let submitObj = document.querySelector('#showBtn');

formObj.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){ 
  if(emailObj.value === '' || passObj.value === ''){
     document.querySelector('#showBtn').style.right="-300px";
  }else{
     document.querySelector('#showBtn').style.right="40%";
  }
});

submitObj.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 alert('do somthing')
});
```

```css
#container{
position: relative;
width:80%;
margin: 10px auto;
}
#btn-container button{
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
  transition: 1s;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#showBtn {
  top: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <form id="my-form">
     <input id="email" type="email">
     <input id="password" type="password">
     <div id="btn-container"><button id="showBtn">Submit</button> </div>
   </form>
</div>
```